# Upgraded to Magento 2.4.2 giving 404 Error

Tags: magento2

I recently upgraded from 2.3.5-p1 to 2.4.0 and everything was working fine. I then upgraded Magento 2.4.0 to 2.4.2, however this time I got 404 Error on the website. Upon checking the logs I found that now Magento is loading data from `website.com/pub` rather then `website.com`.

I think Magento recently changed docroot to `pub` and mentioned [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html)

But I am not sure how will this work, I changed `root` in nginx.conf and added `pub`. But it didn't work.

My nginx.conf file is given below:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
        server  unix:/run/php-fpm/website.sock;
}
server {

  listen 80 backlog=65535;
  server_name website.com www.website.com;
  #root /var/www/domain;

  return 301 https://www.website.com$request_uri;
}
server {

  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name website.com;
  keepalive_timeout 70;
  root /var/www/domain/pub;
  return 301 https://www.website.com$request_uri;

  gzip on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!3DES;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/conf.d/dhparam.pem;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_tickets off;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
}
server {

  listen 443 ssl http2 backlog=65535;
  server_name www.website.com;
  pagespeed off;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!3DES;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/conf.d/dhparam.pem;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_tickets off;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

  #OCSP
  ssl_trusted_certificate  /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/chain.pem;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;

  #add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/website.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/website.error.log;

  set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/website;
  include /var/www/website/nginx.conf.sample;
}
## Example configuration:
# upstream fastcgi_backend {
#    # use tcp connection
#    # server  127.0.0.1:9000;
#    # or socket
#    server   unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
# }
# server {
#    listen 80;
#    server_name mage.dev;
#    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2;
#    set $MAGE_DEBUG_SHOW_ARGS 0;
#    include /vagrant/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
# }
#
## Optional override of deployment mode. We recommend you use the
## command 'bin/magento deploy:mode:set' to switch modes instead.
##
## set $MAGE_MODE default; # or production or developer
##
## If you set MAGE_MODE in server config, you must pass the variable into the
## PHP entry point blocks, which are indicated below. You can pass
## it in using:
##
## fastcgi_param  MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;
##
## In production mode, you should uncomment the 'expires' directive in the /static/ location block

# Modules can be loaded only at the very beginning of the Nginx config file, please move the line below to the main config file
# load_module /etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset UTF-8;
error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
#add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";


# Deny access to sensitive files
location /.user.ini {
    deny all;
}

# PHP entry point for setup application
location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=600";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

# PHP entry point for update application
location ~* ^/update($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /pub/ {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|custom_options|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|html|json)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/ {

## The following section allows to offload image resizing from Magento instance to the Nginx.
## Catalog image URL format should be set accordingly.
## See https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/configuration/general/web.html#url-options
#   location ~* ^/media/catalog/.* {
#
#       # Replace placeholders and uncomment the line below to serve product images from public S3
#       # See examples of S3 authentication at https://github.com/anomalizer/ngx_aws_auth
#       # resolver 8.8.8.8;
#       # proxy_pass https://<bucket-name>.<region-name>.amazonaws.com;
#
#       set $width "-";
#       set $height "-";
#       if ($arg_width != '') {
#           set $width $arg_width;
#       }
#       if ($arg_height != '') {
#           set $height $arg_height;
#       }
#       image_filter resize $width $height;
#       image_filter_jpeg_quality 90;
#   }

    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/custom_options/ {
    deny all;
}

location /errors/ {
    location ~* \.xml$ {
        deny all;
    }
}

# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss
    image/svg+xml;
gzip_vary on;

# Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
location ~* (\.php$|\.phtml$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
    deny all;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I was able to figure it out by adding `pub` at the end of every root path, and now its working but with broken media i.e. image, also I am unable to login on frontend and backend. I get error  `This is not implemented, as it is not possible to implement Argon2i with acceptable performance in pure-PHP`. Even though I have installed php-sodium.

Comment: did you have any custom setting in your root .htaccess ? this file is overwritten during updates. 2.4 will work from / and /pub/

Comment: I was able to figure it out by adding `pub` at the end of every dir, and now its working but with broken media i.e. images also I am unable to login on frontend and backend. I get error ` This is not implemented, as it is not possible to implement Argon2i with acceptable performance in pure-PHP`. Even though I have installed php-sodium

Comment: can you also update the content of the nginx file to the version you have it now?

Comment: @DianaBotean I have updated the new nginx config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your document root in the nginx configuration should be relative to the /pub folder:

```
 root /var/www/website/pub;
```

if you are using the $MAGE_ROOT variable, then you should set it as `set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/website/pub;` and use it everywhere as $MAGE_ROOT, no need to add `<something>/pub` anywhere afterwards. also your config file is a bit messy and hard to parse if you are using so many root definitions with inconsistencies. I recommend you use a uniform way across the whole file.

Comment: hi, i have updated the question with new errors now(

Comment: I also updated my answer based on your latest nginx file content.

Comment: I have alreadt set `set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/website;` in the config. I am using default config file available in the root folder of magento. Above is only the redirection and SSL configs.

Comment: When I login to admin, I get sodium error, even though I have already installed sodium for php and exists in `php -m`.